# How to configure global supervisor to use pyenv and virtualenv

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv, uwsgi, supervisord

I am upgrading a Django installation from 1.4 to 1.7, which means I am also migrating from Python 2.6.6 to Python 2.7. The production server uses Debian 6.09, which requires python 2.6 globally, and unfortunately upgrading the OS is not a valid solution at this time.

To get around this, I installed the following stack:

- pyenv with python 2.7
- virtualenv
- virtualenvwrapper
- uwsgi
- supervisor (installed from the global python 2.6, run as root)
- nginx

When I run uwsgi manually from the the virtualenv, the site works great. However, when I start it with supervisor, it will only use the global python install.

As user with virtualenv:

```
(django1.7)user@staging:~$ echo $PATH
/home/user/.virtualenvs/django1.7/bin:/home/user/.pyenv/shims:/home/user/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

My supervisor config file:

```
[program:app]
command = /home/user/.virtualenvs/django1.7/bin/uwsgi
  --module app.wsgi
  --socket 127.0.0.1:10001
  --master
  --harakiri 120
  --max-requests 5000
  --threads 6
directory=/home/user/app/
environment=PATH="/home/user/.virtualenvs/django1.7/bin:/home/user/.pyenv/shims:/home/user/.pyenv/bin:",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="app.settings",HOME="/home/user"
user=user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

Can anyone help point out where my config is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uWSGI has a specific `virtualenv` configuration directive:

```
  virtualenv=/home/user/.virtualenvs/django1.7
```

Another example:

https://github.com/miohtama/LibertyMusicStore/blob/master/conf/uwsgi.ini

More information

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/dreamhost.html?highlight=virtualenv

(Looks like uWSGI documentation regarding `virtualenv` is bit confusing, I might need to double check this with the authors)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I ended up not modifying the wsgi configuration, and it was a foolish thing on my end.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration I posted ended up working. I was foolish and did not run supervisorctl update first to make sure it loaded in the updated configuration.